# Mapstruct java.util.Stack converting

Tags: java, stack, mapstruct

So, I have three Java classes.

```
class A {
   private Long id; 
   //getter, setter, etc
}

class B {
   private Stack<A> myField;
   //getter, setter, etc
}

class C {
   private Stack<Long> myField;
}
```

I want to convert objects of class B to objects of class C, the order of both stacks should be the same.

I know how to do it manually through additional structure, looping, etc. But is any elegant way to do it through Mapstruct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after several tries, the most elegant way I've found for now is the next:

```
@Mapper
public interface CMapper {

    C BtoC(B b);

    default Long myFieldConverter(A myField) {
        return myField.getId();
    }
}
```

I manually invokes getId() but at least I don't iterate through collection.

I tried to do something with annotations like

```
@Mapping(target = "", source = "id")
Long myFieldConverter(A myField);
```

but haven't found what to put into target, cause field is not any bean, but Long without any fields, setters, etc. And I failed to found a way to put a reference to constructor in "target".